# Using the Bootstrap wizard control but how do you prevent going to a different tab when validation fails in a tab

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using hte Bootstrap wizard.  The user can either click the next or previous button or the tabs above to switch to different pages in the wizard.
On one page in the wizard I need to validate if one number is bigger than another.  If it isn't then the validation fails.  Pushing the next button will not go to the next page.  The problem happens when the user pushes the tab to a later tab and wizard lets them go to that new page in the wizard.

My javascript html code looks like:

```js
    @* Javascript code for the wizard *@
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
                onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {

                    if(WizardValidation(index) == false)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                },

                onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index)
                {
                    if (WizardValidation(tab[0].getAttribute('data-index')) == false) {
                        return false;
                    }
                },

                onTabShow: function (tab, navigation, index) {

                    if (WizardValidation(tab[0].getAttribute('data-index')) == false) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
                    var $current = index + 1;
                    var $percent = ($current / $total) * 100;
                    $('#rootwizard').find('.progress-bar').css({ width: $percent + '%' });
                }
            });
            window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint()
        });


        function WizardValidation(gotoIndex)
        {
            // Validation for various parts in the wizard
            if (gotoIndex > 2) {
                var oDaysMin = document.getElementById('OobeDaysMin').value

                if (oDaysMin.length == 0) {
                    alert('You must enter a valid integer value');
                    document.getElementById('OobeDaysMin').focus();
                    return false;
                }

                var oDaysMax = document.getElementById('OobeDaysMax').value

                if (oDaysMax.length == 0) {
                    alert('You must enter a valid integer value');
                    document.getElementById('OobeDaysMax').focus();
                    return false;
                }

                if ((parseInt(oDaysMax, 10) < parseInt(oDaysMin, 10))) {
                    alert('OobeDaysMax must be equal or greater than OobeDaysMin');
                    document.getElementById('OobeDaysMax').focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
            <section id="wizard">
                <div id="rootwizard">

                    <div class="navbar">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <div class="container">
                                <ul>
                                    <li id="wiz0" data-index="0"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Name</a></li>
                                    <li id="wiz1" data-index="1"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Questions / Layout</a></li>
                                    <li id="wiz2" data-index="2"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Configuration</a></li>
                                    <li id="wiz3" data-index="3"><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Assests / Themes</a></li>
                                    <li id="wiz4" data-index="4"><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Quota Mgmt</a></li>
                                    <li id="wiz5" data-index="5"><a href="#tab6" data-toggle="tab">Go Live</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I have tried using the onTabClick and the onTabShow events to try to prevent allowing someone to go to a page after the page with the validation error.
Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("href");
    console.log(target);
    if (target == "#hesapbilgileri") {
        if ($('#anlasmakabulcheck').is(':checked')) {
            $('.test .wz-steps a[href="#first"]').tab('show');   
        }
        else
            $('.test .wz-steps a[href="#second"]').tab('show');   
    }
});
```